# I would like to keep first link as default selected with javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to keep first link as default selected with javascript, here is my code. currently it shows the active state and hover state. But I would like to keep the first link as by default selected and when user click on second link the first link will come at its normal state.:

```
<table width=100% height=20% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
       style=margin:20px>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a onclick="selectElement(this)"
      href=javascript:getBasicInfoPanel();
      style=font-weight:normal
      class="linkbold">Basic</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style=padding-top:5px;>
   <a onclick="selectElement(this)"
      href=javascript:getNetworkPanel();
      style=font-weight:normal
      class="linkbold">Network</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style=padding-top:5px;>
   <a onclick="selectElement(this)"
      href=javascript:getNetworkPanel2();
      style=font-weight:normal
      class="linkbold">Basic3</a>   
  <td>
 </tr>
</table> 

var selectedElement;
function selectElement(elem) {
    /* Select new element */
    elem.attributes["class"].value = "linkbolds";
    /* Unselect currently selected */
    if (selectedElement) {
        selectedElement.attributes["class"].value = "linkbold";
    }
    selectedElement = elem;
}
```

Comment: You have ExtJS as a tag, what's the context of the function you have here. Are you binding it using ExtJS? Are you trying to use ExtJS as part of your solution or are you trying to use plain JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I am binding it using Extjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this is what you need -

```
var selectedElement; 
function selectElement(elem) {     
   /* Select new element */     
   elem.className = "linkbolds";//used className instead of attributes["class"].value 

   /* Unselect currently selected */     
   if (selectedElement) {         
      selectedElement.className = "linkbold";//used className instead
   }     

   selectedElement = elem; 
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want my first element should be selected by default. here is my code for links:

<tr><td><a onclick="selectElement(this)" href=javascript:getBasicInfoPanel(); style=font-weight:normal class="linkbold">Basic</a><td></tr>
<tr><td style=padding-top:5px;><a onclick="selectElement(this)" href=javascript:getNetworkPanel(); style=font-weight:normal class="linkbold">Network</a><td></tr>

Comment: I have 5 links, out of which the first link should get highlight by default when page loads.

Comment: put your `table` code inside your question above so we can look at it. What you need to do is have an onLoad function which will set the first element className

Comment: <table width=100% height=20% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style=margin:20px><tr><td><a onclick="selectElement(this)" href=javascript:getBasicInfoPanel(); style=font-weight:normal class="linkbold">Basic</a><td></tr><tr><td style=padding-top:5px;><a onclick="selectElement(this)" href=javascript:getNetworkPanel(); style=font-weight:normal class="linkbold">Network</a><td></tr><tr><td style=padding-top:5px;><a onclick="selectElement(this)" href=javascript:getInitiatorGroupPanel(); style=font-weight:normal class="linkbold">Initiator Groups</a><td></tr></table>

Comment: as i said you will need to create an onLoad function . see the fiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/kshz8/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ExtJS, then you can do this like this:

```
Ext.select('a').on('click', function(e, target){
    Ext.select('a').removeCls('linkbold');
    Ext.get(target).addCls('linkbold');
}, null, {preventDefault:true});​
```

This assumes markup like:

```
​<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And let's say some CSS like:

```
​a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.linkbold {
    background-color: #c00;
}​
```

​See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element for more documentation on manipulating Ext elements.

---

**Edit**

Updated JavaScript:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.select('table a').on('click', function(e, target){
        Ext.select('table a').removeCls('linkbold');
        Ext.get(target).addCls('linkbold');
    }, null, {preventDefault:false});

});
```

Updated HTML:​

```
<table width="100%" height="20%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
       style="margin:20px">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="javascript:getBasicInfoPanel();"
      style="font-weight:normal"
      class="linkbold">Basic</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="padding-top:5px;">
   <a href="javascript:getNetworkPanel();"
      style="font-weight:normal">Network</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="padding-top:5px;">
   <a href="javascript:getNetworkPanel2();"
      style="font-weight:normal">Basic3</a>   
  <td>
 </tr>
</table> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I want to do it through javascript. here is my css
.linkbold{
 color:#0080cc;
 font-family:Tahoma;
 font-size:11px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:bold !important;
}
.linkbolds{
 color:#000000;
 font-family:Tahoma;
 font-size:11px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:bold !important;
}

Comment: I would like it append for perticular links for which i have applied css on hyperlinks, not all links on my page starts with a tag.

Comment: I have 5 links, out of which the first link should get highlight by default when page loads.